# Close captions (CC/aka subtitles) file to speech

Tags: video, youtube

Is there a tool which creates an audio file from written text (Is is NOT(!) about speech to text). There are many tools doing this, but I have not found one which is timestamp based.

As I have already the subtitle/cc files, I want to use those existing files. And the timing needs to be considered. Something like this:

```
00:13 Say this
00:17 Say something else
```

So after 13secs the 1st text should be spoken, the second one after 17secs.